# WPF: How to communicate two usercontrols correctly, using MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm developing an WPF (C#) application using MVVM. I've created a new project which is a simplification that focuses only on the problem I have.

In the View there is a Panel which is composed by a PanelButton which consists on two buttons and PanelDisplay.

The idea is that when orange button is pressed the PanelDisplay should change its color to orange and when green button is pressed PanelDisplay should change to green.

Code for Panel:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.View.Panel"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:view="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.View"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="600">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.7*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    
        <view:PanelButtons Grid.Column="0"></view:PanelButtons>
        <view:PanelDisplay Grid.Column="1"></view:PanelDisplay>
                        
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The code for PanelButtons.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.View.PanelButtons"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.ViewModel"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <viewModel:PanelButtonsAndDisplayVM x:Key="panelButtonsAndDisplayVM"/>        
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid Background="LightGray">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Width="64" Height="64"
                Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource panelButtonsAndDisplayVM}, Path=PressedOrange}">Orange</Button>
        <Button Width="64" Height="64"
                Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource panelButtonsAndDisplayVM}, Path=PressedGreen}">Green</Button>
    </StackPanel>
        
</Grid>
```

The code for PanelDisplay.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.View.PanelDisplay"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.ViewModel"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <viewModel:PanelButtonsAndDisplayVM x:Key="panelButtonsAndDisplayVM"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid Background="{Binding Source={StaticResource panelButtonsAndDisplayVM},Path=Color}" >
        
</Grid>
```

The problem is that PanelDisplay does not change its color, to solve this I made a singleton class that launched an event and subscribed PanelDisplay to that event and it worked, but I need two "Panels" in the MainWindow, so if I use this solution the two panels will change their color because they'll both get the same event and only one PanelDisplay should be updated.

Code for the MainWindow:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:view="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.View"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.5*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.5*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    
    <view:Panel Grid.Row="0"/>
    <view:Panel Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

So, how can be actualized each PanelDisplay separately? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PanelButtons.xaml and PanelDisplay.xaml do not use the same instance of PanelButtonsAndDisplayVM class because each is declaring their own instance in resources.

Instead, declare PanelButtonsAndDisplayVM instance in Panel.xaml as DataContext so it is propagated to all descendant controls:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.View.Panel"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:view="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.View"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="600">
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <view:PanelButtonsAndDisplayVM/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.7*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <view:PanelButtons Grid.Column="0"></view:PanelButtons>
        <view:PanelDisplay Grid.Column="1"></view:PanelDisplay>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And use it in PanelButtons.xaml like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.View.PanelButtons"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.ViewModel"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid Background="LightGray">
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Width="64" Height="64"
                Command="{Binding PressedOrange}">Orange</Button>
            <Button Width="64" Height="64"
                Command="{Binding PressedGreen}">Green</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And in PanelDisplay.xaml like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.View.PanelDisplay"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.ViewModel"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid Background="{Binding Path=Color}">
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create a separate viewmodel for each `UserControl`. For example you could have a `PanelViewModel` then as properties on that a `PanelDisplayViewModel` and a `PanelButtonsViewModel`.

1. A button is pressed on the `PanelButtonsViewModel`.
2. That method makes a call up to `PanelViewModel` to report the event.
3. The panel then updates the display by calling a method on the `PanelDisplayViewModel`.

Avoid the static resources for view models here and just use the standard `DataContext` on each user control and it should work out.